# Generate fresh personalized feed for user

Tags: android, server, feed

I am trying to build a social app in which people can share their thoughts, like others' thoughts and comment also. I have a server and android app on client side as for now. My problem is that I want to make sure that user sees everything fresh each time activity is loaded such that server and client both can handle that much load. How do I determine how much data user has actually read from data sent by server and tell that to server so that server can keep check on what to send next?

One example I can think of is quora. It generates new feed each time although show how much i have read before at the end.

Comment: Buddy you should read tutorials first !

Comment: about what exactly? can you provide link or topic?

Comment: _How to refresh data while activity starts_

Comment: I don't think you got my question right. For example, Server sent 10 feed items to app user. I showed them in app. Now when next time I request server to send more data, I don't know whether user actually consumed past 10 feeds. So if I keep check on server side, past 10 feeds are lost for user if he hasn't consumed it.